# Stretch background image to occupy full height of div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've divided screen to 2 parts and want to have same height for both the divs.

What I want is left side div should have same height and should occupy the height same as right part.

When I see this screen in mobile format it is not showing proper.

I tried using height 100% but not working. What am I missing over here?

This is what I've tried.
[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/passtim95269631/pen/rNLvxKJ)

```css
#main_header_div{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(152, 38, 38, 0.7);
    color:white;
}
#div_1_text {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: white;
}

#div_2_text {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: white;
}

#div_3_text {
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: white;
}
#div_4_button {
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="height:100%; background : url('https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50566935741_ba2c76c194_b.jpg');">
            <div id="main_header_div">
                <h3 id="div_1_text">Image Taken From Flickr !</h3>
                <p id="div_2_text">For DEMO</p>
                <p id="div_3_text">TEXT 3</p>
                <button id="div_4_button" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">BUTTON</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;">
        <div style="width:100%;">
            <img class="image-responsive" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50566935741_ba2c76c194_b.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want that left `div` and right `div` stay respectively on the left and on the right in mobile format?

Comment: @zerbene No, I want them to be one below the other on mobile screen

Answer (score 0):

I found this (I cheat a little by given a fix size to the `div`: `myDiv`, who has the background-image because I think that background-image doesn't have size):

```css
.myDiv{
  height: 680px; /*manual check to get image height*/
}

#main_header_div{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(152, 38, 38, 0.7);
}
#div_1_text {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: white;
}

#div_2_text {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: white;
}

#div_3_text {
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: white;
}
#div_4_button {
    margin-left: 15%;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid myDiv" style="background : url('https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50566935741_ba2c76c194_b.jpg');">
            <div id="main_header_div">
                <h3 id="div_1_text">Image Taken From Flickr !</h3>
                <p id="div_2_text">For DEMO</p>
                <p id="div_3_text">TEXT 3</p>
                <button id="div_4_button" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">BUTTON</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;">
        <div style="width:100%;">
            <img class="image-responsive" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50566935741_ba2c76c194_b.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Yeah I've tried your solution, but I want left side image to look like transparent hence I was using that background color property which was making it position absolute.